# Calculate angle of triangle

Tags: vector-spaces, triangles, solid-angle

I need to calculate the angle between two sides, I have the length of A & B sides, but don't know how to find the angle...

Both sides are the same length.

I can get the start and end vectors of each side, I can also get the center values of each side.

Here's an image better describing my question:

[image]

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: You only know two sides and no angle. This is not enough information to calculate that angle.

Comment: What additional information do you need?

Comment: As I said I don't know! :( but what else do you need to calculate the angle? I'll see if I can get it @Alizter

Comment: What else do you need @imranfat?

Comment: If you know the coordinates of start- and endpoints of A and B, it would help.

Comment: Yes I do have the coords of the start and end point @DoctorDan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have points:
$$A=(A_x, A_y),\ B=(B_x,B_y)$$
And two equal sides with length $l$ originating from a shared point $O=(0,0)$, then the angle between $AO$ and $BO$ will be:
$$\cos\theta = \frac{AO\cdot BO}{l^2}$$
$$\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{A_xB_x+A_yB_y}{l^2}\right)$$
This is just a particular case of the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Wow, that's great!

Comment: so what would A/b be actually equal to? the end point of each side?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins - yes. A could be, say (1,2) And B would be say (2,1), both would have the same distance from the origin (0,0).

Comment: Just to be clear here, those coordinates of the endpoints were NOT given in the question. And if these coordinates were, say A(4,1) and B(1,4), that angle would be different!

Comment: @imranfat - I'm sure no one would have thought otherwise. That's the meaning of the word "say": this is just a particular example.

Comment: so let's say the following: the `center x and y is 0`

`A x and y is equal to 20`
`Length = 7`
`B x and y is equal to 30`

Would the equation look like this:

`o1 = cos((0*0) / 14)`
`o2 = cos(((20*30) + (20*30)) / 14)`