# Check point is between two points

Tags: geometry

I want to check whether $(x_3,y_3)$ is between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

"between" means this:

[image]

Comment: What did you try ? What is the second figure for ?

Comment: the point should be in between these two lines. I want to check that.

Comment: That depends on the lengths of those thin lines, what are they? Are they the same?

Comment: The angles $\widehat{A_3A_1A_2}$ and $\widehat{A_3A_2A_1}$ should be acute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the perpendicular from point 3 on the line between point 1 and point 2, and see where the foot point of this perpendicular is.

That is, compute the difference between the endpoints of the line
$$
d_0 = \pmatrix{x_2-x_1\\y_2-y_1}
$$
and its direction
$$
v = d_0 / ||d_0|| 
$$
Then compute the vector from the start point of the line to the point in question
$$
d_1 = \pmatrix{x_3-x_1\\y_3-y_1}
$$
And finally, the dot product
$$
r = v * d_1 
$$
When this dot product is in the range $[0, ||d_0||]$, then the point is between the other points.

Answer (score 2):

If $\exists t$, such that
$$
\pmatrix{x_2-x_1\\y_2-y_1}t + \pmatrix{x_1\\y_1}=\pmatrix{x_3\\y_3},
$$
then $\pmatrix{x_3\\y_3}$ lies between the two others..

**EDIT**

Complete the triangle. If the angles at $\pmatrix{x_2\\y_2}$ or $\pmatrix{x_1\\y_1}$ are both less than $90^\circ$ then $\pmatrix{x_3\\y_3}$ is between. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/480985/19341) how to calculate the angles...

Comment: what is this "t" means

Comment: @JanithOCoder just a parameter: if there is a value for $t$, then you know that the third point lies directly on the line between the first and the second point, but only the stuff after **EDIT** seems to be relevant for you...